# Existe alguma forma de gravar a webcam pelo HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html5, vídeo

Eu sei que existe uma forma (inclusive já usei em pelo menos uns 5 sistemas que eu desenvolvi) de abrir a webcam pelo HTML5 e capturar uma foto (eu faço isso utilizando o `canvas`).

[Exemplo de Captura através da câmera com html5](https://jsfiddle.net/3r6h3qan/1/)

Porém me surgiu uma dúvida: Eu posso capturar essa imagem da câmera, salvar num arquivo de vídeo temporário e depois enviar para o servidor?

Comment: Isso te ajuda? https://www.html5rocks.com/pt/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/

Comment: https://github.com/aojsamurai/Webcam-html5-record-video-audio-getUserMedia

Comment: Tem também essa biblioteca: [RecordRTC](https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC). Captura em diversos formatos e containers (gif, webm, vp8, vp9, webm...)

Comment: <h3>Solução Prática: Open Source</h3> Existe o [RecordRTC-to-PHP](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/RecordRTC/RecordRTC-to-PHP) projeto open-source, grava audio e vídeo, e transfere o dado por meio de POST php Tem outro projeto similar: [RcordRTC-to-PHP-and-FFmpeg](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/RecordRTC/PHP-and-FFmpeg).

Answer (score 2):

A **captura de áudio/vídeo** tem sido o **"Santo Graal"** do desenvolvimento web há muito tempo. Por muitos anos, temos usado **plug-ins de navegadores (Flash ou Silverlight)** para fazer isto.. Mas tudo mudou e se atualiza com o passar do tempo, vamos lá !

**Histórico de getUserMedia()**

> Se você não conhece a história, vale dizer que o modo como chegamos à
>   API getUserMedia() é um conto interessante.
>
> Nos últimos anos, foram desenvolvidas diversas variações de "APIs de
>   captura de mídia". Muitos colegas reconheceram a necessidade de
>   conseguir acessar dispositivos nativos na web, mas isso levou ao
>   desenvolvimento de uma nova especificação. As coisas ficaram tão
>   confusas que o [W3C](https://www.w3schools.com/) finalmente decidiu formar um grupo de trabalho. O
>   objetivo? Arrumar a bagunça. [O grupo de trabalho DAP (política de APIs
>   de dispositivo)](http://www.w3.org/2009/dap/) tinha a tarefa de consolidar e padronizar a variedade
>   de propostas.

**Exemplo: Captura de Mídia HTML**

> [A captura de mídia HTML](http://dev.w3.org/2009/dap/camera/) foi a primeira tentativa do DAP de padronizar
>   a captura de mídia na web. Ela funciona sobrepondo `<input type="file">` e adicionando novos valores para o parâmetro accept.
>
> Os usuários possam fazer uma captura de tela por conta própria com a
>   webcam usando capture=camera:
>
> ```
> <input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">
> ```
>
> A gravação de um vídeo ou áudio é semelhante:
>
> ```
> <input type="file" accept="video/*;capture=camcorder">
> <input type="file" accept="audio/*;capture=microphone">
> ```
>
> Muito bom, não é? Particularmente, gosto da reutilização de uma
>   entrada de arquivo. Semanticamente, isso faz muito sentido. O ponto
>   fraco dessa "API" específica está em sua capacidade de criar efeitos
>   em tempo real (por exemplo, processar dados ao vivo da webcam em um
>    e aplicar filtros WebGL). A captura de mídia HTML só permite
>   gravar um arquivo de mídia ou fazer uma captura de tela por vez.
>
> Suporte:
>
> Navegador Android 3.0 - uma das primeiras implementações. Confira este
>   vídeo para vê-lo em ação. Google Chrome para Android (0.16) Minha
>   recomendação é não utilizá-lo, a não ser que você esteja trabalhando
>   com um dos navegadores para celular acima. Os fornecedores estão
>   migrando para getUserMedia(). É muito improvável que mais alguém
>   implemente a captura de mídia HTML em longo prazo.

**Para entrar mais afundo, acesse os hiperlinks que foi passado!**